# How to dynamically set query parameters with AWS AppSync SDK for React-Native

Tags: react-native, graphql, aws-appsync

**Background:** I'm working on building a mobile app with react-native, and am setting up AWS's AppSync for synchronizing the app with cloud data sources.

**The challenge**: I have a view which shows all items in a list. The list's ID is passed in as a prop to the component. I need to use that list ID to query for the items of that list. I have the query working fine if I hard-code the list ID, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to dynamically set the list ID for the query when props update.

Here's what I have working (with a hard-coded ID of testList01) in my **ListPage** component:

```
const getListItems = id => gql`
    query getListItems {
      getListItems(listID: ${id}) {
        reference_id,
        quantity,
      }
    }
  `;

export default graphql(getListItems('testList01'), { 
  options: {
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
  },
  props: props => ({
    listItems: props.data ? props.data.getListItems : [],
    data: props.data,
  }),
})(withNavigationFocus(ListPage));
```

I would like to be able to dynamically set which list to look up the items for based on a list ID, which is being passed in from props. Specifically, I'm using react-navigation to enter the ListPage, a view where a user can see the items on a List. So here's the code that gets executed when a user clicks on a list name and gets routed to the ListPage component:

```
  handleListSelection(list: Object) {
    const { navigation, userLists } = this.props;
    navigation.navigate('ListPage', {
      listID: list.record_id,
      listName: list.list_name,
      userLists,
    });
  }
```

From my previous (pre-AppSync/GraphQL) implementation, I know that I can access the list ID in ListPage via `this.props.navigation.state.params.listID`. I would like to be able to use that in my AppSync query, but because the query is created outside the component, I'm unable to access the props, and so am struggling to get the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this working using a package called react-apollo-dynamic-query which I found [here](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/1207#issuecomment-427401599). The author of that package also links directly to a [simple function](https://github.com/seangransee/react-apollo-dynamic-query/blob/HEAD/src/index.js) for doing what I'm trying to do here. 
Essentially it just wraps the regular graphql call in a simple way that exposes the props so they can be passed down to the query.

My code now looks likes this (which I have below my definition of the ListPage component, in the same file):

```
const getListItems = props => {
   const listID = props.navigation.state.params.listID;
   return gql`
      query getListItems {
        getListItems(listID: "${listID}") { // Note the variable being wrapped in double quotes
          reference_id,
          quantity,
         }
       }
   `;
};

const config = {
  options: {
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
  },
  props: props => ({
    listItems: props.data ? props.data.getListItems : [],
  }),
};

const MyApolloComponent = graphqlDynamic(getListItems, config)(ListPage);

export default MyApolloComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work like this:

```
const getListItems = (id) => {
  return gql`
    query getListItems {
      getListItems(listID: ${id}) {
        reference_id,
        quantity,
      }
    }
  `;
}
```

Call this getListItems like the below

```
export default graphql(getListItems(id), { //from where ever you want to send the id
  options: {
    fetchPolicy: '
    ......
```

I have not tested this code. Please update if this works. Although I am quite sure that it works.

Comment: Thanks @Suraj. This partially works - with your code above, I can get everything working when I test with: export default graphql(getListItems('testList01'), { ... }. But I'm still having trouble passing in the list ID from props. Specifically, I'm using react-navigation to get to the ListPage, so I need to get props.navigation.state.params.listID. But I'm getting errors when I try to access this.props or props in that line. Any insights on how to do that?

Comment: @bohan27 Please add your code from where you are passing the params and the component where you are expecting it. With the existing code. I am not able to infer the scenerio properly.

Comment: Just updated the question with some additional code and context.

Comment: FYI - I also tried this but get an error about "functions are not valid as a react child":      `const queryWithProps = (props: ListPageProps) => (
  graphql(getListItems(props.navigation.state.params.listID), {
    options: {
      fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
    },
    props: props => ({
      listItems: props.data ? props.data.getListItems : [],
    }),
  })(withNavigationFocus(ListPage))
);

export default queryWithProps;`